# SQL: Average of the class of the record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have records like this:

```
name       price    class
Horse      5000     mammal
Cat        3000     mammal
penguin    2000     bird
chicken    1000     bird
turtle     4000     reptile
snake      2400     reptile
```

I need a table with the following collumns: name, price, class, priceavg_of_class
For example:

```
name       price    class    priceavg_of_class
Horse      5000     mammal   4000
Cat        3000     mammal   4000
penguin    2000     bird     1500
chicken    1000     bird     1500
turtle     4000     reptile  3200
snake      2400     reptile  3200
```

How can I solve this problem using SQL?

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT animal.name, animal.price, animal.class, 
(SELECT Avg(animal.price) FROM animal WHERE class = animal.class) AS Avg
FROM animal
```

But It doesn't seem to work. I get the same average value for each record.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I believe it is Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this with an explicit join:

```
select name, price, class, avgprice
from animal t inner join
     (select class, avg(price) as avgprice
      from animal t
      group by class
     ) tavg
     on t.class = tavg.class
```

The problem with your query (which is an alternative solution) is the scoping of the variables.  If you include an alias for all the columns, then it will work:

```
SELECT a.name, a.price, a.class, 
       (SELECT Avg(a2.price) FROM animal a2 WHERE a.class = a2.class
       ) AS Avg
FROM animal a
```

You had `class = animal.class`.  Both of these refer to the `animal` table in the inner query, because the nearest scope is the one used to resolve a column reference.

Comment: thank you :) Actually I didn't know that I can use aliases for tables :)

Answer (score 1):

use a Subquery and aggregate function

```
Select name, price, class, 
    (select Avg(price) From table
     where class = t.class) avgPrice
From table t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name,price,class,avg(price) over (partition by class)
from tab;

SELECT m.name,
  m.price,b.class,b.price
  FROM tab m,
  (SELECT class,AVG(price) price FROM tab GROUP BY class
  ) b
  where m.class=b.class
```